# Enabling/Disabling button through dropdown using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I have following dropdown

```
    <select ng-model="item" ng-options="a.name for a in adda" ng-change="onChange()">
        <option value="">
            Add new account
        </option>
    </select>
```

In my code I have following button..

```
  <button class="btnS btn-success ctrl-btn" ng-click="save()"> Submit</button>
```

What i want the button disabled and only be enabled if one of the options in the drop down is selected. Thanks

Comment: Check this link -- > [ngDisabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ng-disabled`:

```
<button 
   class="btnS btn-success ctrl-btn" 
   ng-click="save()" 
   ng-disabled="!item"> Submit</button>
```